# Unable to access Raspberry Pi through Serial Connection

Tags: serial-console

With the setup I am using, the Pi fills up with logs. The ring buffer I have set up doesn't seem to work and fills the SD card.

I accessed the unit before using serial connection but now I do not get a response from the terminal application.

I used another SD card with the same serial connection without issue. It is isolated to the overloaded SD cards.